# DIV background-image has unwanted outline in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a div with two background images set to repeat. The first image is like a border on the right side of the div repeating on the y-axis. The second image is repeating on the entire div as a texture fill.

It looks as it's supposed to on "all" browsers (Firefox, Safari, IE) except Chrome. In Chrome the image that's repeating on the side of the div has a grey outline separating it from the other image. See images below.

Anyone knows why is it appearing like this on Chrome? Is it purely browser-side issue or can it be fixed by code?

Here's my CSS:

```
background-image: url("door.png"), url("doorfull.png");
background-position: right top, left top;
background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat;
```

I have tried typing the url without quotes, adding `border: none` and I don't know what else but nothing removes the outline on Chrome. Any help much appreciated.

EDIT: The page can be viewed here: http://testsite.matronator.com

Chrome:
[image: Figure 1: Google Chrome]

Safari and other browsers:
[image: Figure 2: Safari (and other browsers)]

Comment: Do you have a link to look at?

Comment: it may be caused by the [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat) repeat-y is the same as saying "no-repeat repeat" NM just noticed you have a "," for multiple images

Comment: @DanielSixl Uploaded the page here: http://testsite.matronator.com

Comment: Looks okay in my Chrome (version 58 on Linux).

Comment: @helb oh, I guess it is an issue with Chrome after all. 58 is dev version if I'm not mistaken, I am using the latest stable release which is 56. So I guess they fixed it in the newer version.

Comment: Did you check your zoom settings? This sometimes causes effects like these. Looks good here, on Win Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).

Comment: Well I guess it's an issue just on Mac. I checked zoom settings and it was on 100% as usual. I tried setting different values and found that the outline doesn't show when it's on 50% and only that. Every other value show the lines. I have retina display on my 'book, couldn't it be somehow related?

Comment: Or better yet, can you set different browser for Live Preview in Brackets? I can't finish the page like this, those lines are driving me crazy even though I'm probably the only one seeing them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was most likely due to buggy rendering on retina displays. Probably a bug in the previous version(s) of Chrome, because everything looks like it's supposed to now (Chrome version 73 on macOS).